# LinkedIn profile name scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape only the profile names from a bunch of LinkedIn URLs that I have. I am using bs4 with python. But no matter what I do the bs4 returns empty array. What is happening?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
r1 = requests.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/agazdecki/")
coverpage = r1.content
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
name_container = soup1.find_all("li", class_ = "inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words")
print(name_container)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *profile name*?

Comment: My guess is because you need to be logged in the view. So you may need to create a session and/or post your credentials for authorisation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkedIn scraping not getting all data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801971/linkedin-scraping-not-getting-all-data)

Comment: Note that scraping `Linkedin` is against `TOS`, so you will can't loop more than 2 times. then you will get blocked. use the `API` instead as the previous answer addressing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First Mistake : you are using requests to fetch the page but you have to know , You must be logged in first so for that you need to use sessions .
2. Second mistake : You are using css selector to get an element which is dynamically generated by JavaScript and is being rendered by the browser so if you view the source code of the page you won't find that `li` tag or the `class` or the profile name anywhere except in a code tag in a json object .

I'm assuming you are using a session

```
import requests , re , json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r1 = requests.Session.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/agazdecki/", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')
info_tag = soup.find('code',text=re.compile('"data":{"firstName":'))
data = json.loads(info_tag.text)
first_name = data['data']['firstName']
last_name = data['data']['lastName']
occupation = data['data']['occupation']
print('First Name :' , first_name)
print('Last Name :' , last_name)
print('occupation :' , occupation)
```

Output:

```
First Name : Andrew
Last Name : Gazdecki
occupation : Chief Revenue Officer @ Spiff. Inc. 30 under 30 Entrepreneur.
```

Comment: thank you, it helped, please can you tell me when should i use selectors and when should i use json?

Comment: can you tell me how to look for when getting data in json

Comment: I mean how do i know where the data is coming from

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar you right click on the page and choose view page source , then search for what you are trying to extract if it's in a normal html tag then use Bs and css selectors to get it , if it's in a json format then extract that object and extract the values the same way you do with dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

If you try to load the page without JavaScript you will see that the
element you are trying to look for doesn't exist. In other words, the whole
LinkedIn page is loaded with Javascript (like [single-page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). In fact, BeautifulSoup is working
as expected and parsing the page it gets, which has the JavaScript code and
not the page you expected.

```
>>> coverpage = r1.content
>>> coverpage
b'<html><head>\n<script type="text/javascript">\nwindow.onload =
function() {\n  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.\n  var trk =
"bf";\n  var trkInfo = "bf";\n  var cookies = document.cookie.split(";
");\n  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {\n    if
((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {\n
 trk = cookies[i].substring(8);\n    }\n    else if
((cookies[i].indexOf("trkInfo=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {\n
 trkInfo = cookies[i].substring(8);\n    }\n  }\n\n  if
(window.location.protocol == "http:") {\n    // If "sl" cookie is set,
redirect to https.\n    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {\n
 if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {\n
 window.location.href = "https:" +
window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);\n
 return;\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  // Get the new domain. For international
domains such as\n  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com\n
 var domain = "www.linkedin.com";\n  if (domain != location.host) {\n
 var subdomainIndex = location.host.indexOf(".linkedin");\n    if
(subdomainIndex != -1) {\n      domain = "www" +
location.host.substring(subdomainIndex);\n    }\n  }\n\n
 window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk +
"&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +\n      "&originalReferer=" +
document.referrer.substr(0, 200) +\n      "&sessionRedirect=" +
encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);\n}\n</script>\n</head></html>'
```

You could try to use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to scrape data using selenium.
Download Chrome WebDriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("Path to your Chrome Webdriver")

#login using webdriver
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login?trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin')
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys('your email_id here')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys('your password here')
sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="submit"]')
sign_in_button.click()


driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/agazdecki/') #change profile_url here.

name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class = "inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"]').text
print(name)
```